# Bind Exception running wicket project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, wicket, embedded-jetty

I was trying to configure wicket with Eclipse. So I generated some commands in quickstart tab, paste it into the terminal new maven project was created. Then I ran mvn eclipse:eclipse command. I imported generated project into Eclipse, then I tried to run **Start.java** and I`ve got some weird errors:
[image]

I thought I could resolve this program by changing jetty port, so I ran `mvn jetty:run -Djetty.http.port=8081` But I've got more errors, which I don`t know hot to resolve.
[image]

Could you help me with that problem, please?

Comment: mvn -Djetty.port=8888 jetty:run. Can you try this command instead of jetty.http.port? Also try to find out which ports are currently occupied. In your case it seems the port conflict is the issue.

Comment: @AritraChatterjee I get the same error as with jetty.http.port

Comment: Can you give this page a quick look -> https://www.mkyong.com/wicket/how-do-setup-wicket-examples-in-eclipse/ and see whether you have followed the same steps mentioned here?

Comment: @AritraChatterjee using this guide, I have the same error, and also Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/wicket/request/Response/Requet errors. Though, I used another [guide](https://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html), because I need to create new wicket project in Eclipse and not just run existing project.

Comment: I always recommend wicket quick start https://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html. To set up my project

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/wicket-7.x/archetypes/quickstart/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/test/jetty/jetty-http.xml#L33 the property name should be `jetty.port`. But it might be that it is not the HTTP port but the HTTPS one (`jetty.https.port`), or even JNDI (by default it binds to 1099).

With Windows usually the easiest way is to restart the OS and try again :-/